# Google oauth2 from an MS Access 2016 application

Tags: ms-access, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I need to create Google calendar entries from an MS Access 2016 application.

To be able to do this, I need to perform an OAuth2 authentication and I am getting a bit desperate right now.

I could find many tips but it none for MS Access (well, some for MS Access but they use an obsolete authentication method so not very useful)

Am I really the first person to try this or is there somewhere out there who has gone this route before me and is willing to share his or her experiences and code?

It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok, after a lot of search and trying, I was able to build a very dirty authentication module. I will clean it up, tidy it up and comment it up and then I will post it as answer to this question. (I will also try to explain a bit more of what I needed)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Could prove very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, for information on Google's oAuth2 and getting your client_id and client_secret, have a look over here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Okay, here goes, this is what I build.

First lets discuss the prerequisites. There are 2 functions that I will not describe here since they tend to be very personal. These functions are:

```
Public Function GetDBSetting(field as string) as string
Public Sub SetSetting(field as string, value as string)
```

These functions get and set settings needed for this to work. You might want to store them in a database table but how you do this is all up to you and outside the scope of this answer.

The settings involved in this solution are:

```
oauth2_client_id       (you get this from google)
oauth2_client_secret   (this is given to you by google as well)
oauth2_scope           (just pick the scope you need)
oauth2_access_token    (this we collect)
oauth2_refresh_token   (this we collect)
oauth2_token_type      (this we collect)
```

For this solution, we need:

- a form (named Browser) with a WebBrowser control (named WebBrowser1),
- a class to place HTTP requests
- a module with some tools

The class looks like this (save this class as HTTP_Response):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' A very simple class to send HTTP requests and receive the resulting body

' These variables hold the results
Public Status As Long
Public StatusText As String
Public responseText As String

' This sub simply sends the request and collects the results

' Headers should be an array of strings with the following format: headername:value
Public Sub sendHTTP(URL As String, Optional METHOD As String = "POST", Optional CONTENT As String = "text/plain", Optional BODY As String = "", Optional addAuth As Boolean = False, Optional Headers As Variant)

    Dim Http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim hdrLine As Variant
    Dim hdrarr As Variant

    Set Http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With Http
        Call .Open(METHOD, URL)
        If CONTENT <> "" Then Call .setRequestHeader("Content-Type", CONTENT)
        If addAuth Then Call .setRequestHeader("Authorization", GetDBSetting("oauth2_token_type") & " " & GetDBSetting("oauth2_access_token"))
        If IsArray(Headers) Then
            For Each hdrLine In Headers
                hdrarr = Split(CStr(hdrLine), ":")
                Call .setRequestHeader(hdrarr(0), hdrarr(1))
            Next
        End If

        Call .send(BODY)

        Status = .Status
        StatusText = .StatusText
        responseText = .responseText
    End With

End Sub
```

This class is only used to make sending HTTP requests and receiving the result easier. Nothing fancy.

The module looks like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' A function that checks if the known token is still valid and tries to request a refresh token if it is not
Public Function checkToken() As Boolean

    Dim resTxt As New HTTP_Response

    Call resTxt.sendHTTP("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_access_token"))
    If resTxt.Status = 200 Then
        checkToken = True
    Else
        checkToken = refreshToken
    End If

End Function

' A function that requests a refresh token
Public Function refreshToken() As Boolean

    Dim authres() As String
    Dim resTxt As New HTTP_Response
    Dim svarbody As String
    Dim aCnt As Integer

    svarbody = "client_secret=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_client_secret") & "&" & _
        "grant_type=refresh_token&" & _
        "refresh_token=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_refresh_token") & "&" & _
        "client_id=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_client_id")

    Call resTxt.sendHTTP("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", svarbody, False)
    If resTxt.Status = 200 Then
        authres = Split(resTxt.responseText, """")

        aCnt = 0
        While aCnt < UBound(authres)
            aCnt = aCnt + 1
            If authres(aCnt) = "access_token" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_access_token", authres(aCnt + 2))
            If authres(aCnt) = "token_type" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_token_type", authres(aCnt + 2))
            If authres(aCnt) = "refresh_token_" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_refresh_token", authres(aCnt + 2))
        Wend
        refreshToken = True
    Else
        refreshToken = False
    End If
End Function

' A sub to revoke a known token
Public Sub revokeToken()

    Dim resTxt As New HTTP_Response

    if checkToken() Then Call resTxt.sendHTTP("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_access_token"))

End Sub
```

You can use these functions to ensure you have a valid access_token.

If you don't have a valid access_token, you can get one by going through the oAuth2 flow where you request specific access (through the value you set in oauth2_scope) by opening the form with the command:

```
Call DoCmd.OpenForm("Browser", acDialog)
```

The Forms VBA code looks like this:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Enum BrowserNavigationFlags
    navOpenInNewWindow = 1      ' Open the resource or file in a new window.
    navNoHistory = 2            ' Do not add the resource or file to the history list. The new page replaces the current page in the list.
    navNoReadFromCache = 4      ' Do not read from the disk cache for this navigation.
    navNoWriteToCache = 8       ' Do not write the results of this navigation to the disk cache.
End Enum

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Call Me.WebBrowser1.Object.Navigate2("about:blank", navNoReadFromCache)
    Call startOauth2
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateError(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, StatusCode As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    ' Due to the redirect URL pointing to Localhost and we don't have a webserver running at localhost (Just make sure we don't!)
    ' The browser triggers the NavigateError event when it receives the URL for localhost
    ' We can now read the URL and extract the received code to request a token

    Dim retCode, getAccessToken As String
    Dim authres() As String
    Dim aCnt As Long
    Dim resTxt As New HTTP_Response

    ' Extract the code from the URL
    retCode = Right(URL, Len(URL) - (InStr(1, URL, "&code=") + 5))
    ' Construct the Body to request a access token and a refresh token
    getAccessToken = "code=" & retCode & "&" & _
        "client_id=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_client_id") & "&" & _
        "client_secret=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_client_secret") & "&" & _
        "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&" & _
        "grant_type=authorization_code"

    ' Send the request
    Call resTxt.sendHTTP("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", "POST", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", getAccessToken)
    ' And receive the tokens
    authres = Split(resTxt.responseText, """")

    ' Now extract the tokens from the received body
    ' I know this can be done differently with a nice JSON class
    aCnt = 0
    While aCnt < UBound(authres)
        aCnt = aCnt + 1
        If authres(aCnt) = "access_token" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_access_token", authres(aCnt + 2))
        If authres(aCnt) = "token_type" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_token_type", authres(aCnt + 2))
        If authres(aCnt) = "refresh_token_" Then Call SetSetting("oauth2_refresh_token", authres(aCnt + 2))
    Wend

    ' And we are done
    Set resTxt = Nothing
    Call DoCmd.Close(acForm, "Browser")
End Sub

Private Sub startOauth2()

    ' Here we start stage 1 of the oAuth2 process
    Dim svarbody As String
    Dim resTxt As New HTTP_Response

    ' First we create a body to request access
    svarbody = "client_id=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_client_id") & "&" & _
        "state=Anything_can_come_here_we_dont_use_it&" & _
        "redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&" & _
        "scope=" & GetDBSetting("oauth2_scope") & "&" & _
        "response_type=code&" & _
        "access_type=offline"

    ' Send the request
    Call resTxt.sendHTTP("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth", "POST", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", svarbody)
    ' And write the result to the WebBrowser control on the form
    Call Me.WebBrowser1.Object.Document.Write(resTxt.responseText)

    Set resTxt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Now, I have tried to make this as clear as I can but there will always be questions. Please don't hesitate to ask and I will be happy to try and answer them.

Comment: @ede-brito The first class should be named HTTP_Response (I edited the answer to reflect that)